# Select a set and work on with this set within a scope (or function)

Tags: jquery

I'm not quite sure how to explain this properly.
What I want is select a element and it's childs like

```
$('div#foo');
```

and then work on with this set, so that jQuery only knows about this set, so it would be something like this:

```
$('div#foo').function() {
    $('div#firstChildOfFoo').attr('width');
    // DO OTHER STUFF WITH THIS SET.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you only want the first child? Or do you want all children?

Comment: I need all children, the whole set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/zUCHk/)**

```
$('#foo img').each(function(){

  alert($(this).width());

});
```

Comment: But this would just loop through the set, right? I want to simulate, that the selected set is the whole DOM.

Comment: Than just use the `*` selector. If I understand you well ... than all you parent elements should have a `.class` also and than do: `$('.foo img').each(function(){ /* CODE HERE */ });` instead of `#foo`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [first-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).

```
$('div#foo :first-child').attr('width');
```

**Update**

Are you looking for something like this? Here I'm demonstrating how you can use a selector to find elements within the scope of the set `$foo`.

```
bar($('div#foo'));

function bar($foo) 
{
    $(".some-selector", $foo).css('width', '10px');
    $(".some-other-selector", $foo).css('height', '50px');
    // DO OTHER STUFF WITH THIS SET.
}
```

Comment: I know, but I need to do more than just this single statement and need to fetch other elements in this set. Because of that, I want to somehow wrap this in a function.

Comment: Are you doing the same operation for each item in the set?